# What is the expression for sofa or cushion "go down"?

Tags: expression-choice

As we usually sit on the sofa or use cushion, it is not the condition of the first one. The part we usually sit become sunk(?)/ go down.

Then how can I say this?

> Sofa [went down?].

Comment: I like to call this part of my couch "the comfy spot", though it's long since evolved into what I now call "the memory hole". You can just call it "sunken in", if you like. I don't know if there's a common term for it: others will probably weigh in with ideas.

Comment: When we sit on a sofa, it simply changes its **shape**. It doesn't go down.

Comment: Are you asking for a temporarily depressed sofa? Or that depression remains always as a result of sitting on that always?

Comment: A sofa can sag in the well-used spots.

Comment: Are you talking about what happens when you sit down on the couch (your weight creates a depression which disappears again when you get up), or about the more permanent indent that slowly builds up if you sit in the same spot on the couch every day for several years (an indent which doesn’t go away even after you get back up)? Ahmed’s suggestion that the couch _sags_ implies the second, that it’s a permanent feature of the couch; if it’s the first you’re after, the answer will be different.

Answer (score 4):

Your can try **[sag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sag)**, if the depression of the sofa is permanent, rather than temporary.

> **Sag** [VERB] from Oxford Dictionaries.

**1.** Sink, subside, or bulge downwards **under weight or pressure** or through lack of strength.

> 'the sofa **sagged**'.

Comment: This works perfectly, yet isn't quite precise. Sagging would suggest a larger affected area. But, I repeat, it is quite legit in this case.

Comment: Agree with you... Well the OP's question still looks unclear somehow. He's either asking for temporary depression after sitting, or a depression that remains always.

Comment: True. It's not his fault, though. Nor should he lose hope completely. Once I've given them a dozen discounted drawing lessons, he'll be able to illustrate his questions with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The sofa ***yields*** to the sitter's weight, becoming ***concave*** in that area. There's a marked ***depression*** in the sofa in the area favored by the owner.

Comment: +1. Depression might work here, as saying 'the sofa got depressed when I sat on it'

Comment: @Ahmed I don’t think sofas have quite enough awareness and sense of self to get depressed.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people throwing out the word "depression," but no one mentioning the verb, [**Depress**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50442?rskey=utCQ7b&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid). From OED:

> To press down (in space). Often more widely: To force, bring, move, or put into a lower position by any physical action; to lower.

You could use this as "The sofa depressed as I sank into it." Or if you're feeling cheeky, "My lonely sofa used to be depressed until it was given more depressions."